# Android list footer

Tags: java, android

I get a null pointer exception at line five/seven of my code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_row, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
    TextView tv_footer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_footertext);
    if(getListView().getCount()<=8) {
        tv_footer.setText("You have no more assignments");
    } else {
        tv_footer.setText(Integer.toString(getListView().getCount()) + " assignments shown");
    }
    getListView().addFooterView(header, null, false);
```

I'm not too sure why, so could you tell me? List view's aren't my thing.

I'll tick the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `findViewById()` method from your `Activity`'s `View` you should assign (which I assume is the footer `TextView` in your `R.layout.footer_row`) the `TextView` from the inflated `View`.

Sample code:

```
TextView tv_footer = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_footertext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change third line of your code as specified below. as your inflated view contains the textView you specified.

```
TextView tv_footer = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_footertext);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is correct, but the other guy answered first and so got the tick. Thankyou anyway!

Comment: Anyways Thaknks for clicking the upper triangle.:).

Answer (score 0):

can you post the logcat information,it seems that tv_footer value may not set,It may be R.id.tv_footertext is not the part of layout which you set in the setContentView(....) method check it once.It is better if you provide code in detail(since your posted code seems fine)